# PowerShell - Group-Object Poor Performance

Tags: powershell, group-object

I've written a script to help me identify duplicate files. For some reason if I split these commands and export/import to CSV it runs much faster than if I leave everything in memory. Here is my original code, it is god-awful slow:

```
Get-ChildItem M:\ -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 524288000} | select-object Directory, Name | Group-Object directory | ?{$_.count -gt 1} | %{$_.Group} | export-csv -notypeinformation M:\Misc\Scripts\Duplicates.csv
```

If I split this into 2 commands and export to CSV in the middle it runs about 100x faster. I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

```
Get-ChildItem M:\ -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 524288000} | select-object Directory, Name | Export-Csv -notypeinformation M:\Misc\Scripts\DuplicateMovies\4.csv

import-csv M:\Misc\Scripts\Duplicates\4.csv | Group-Object directory | ?{$_.count -gt 1} | %{$_.Group} | export-csv -notypeinformation M:\Misc\Scripts\Duplicates\Duplicates.csv

remove-item M:\Misc\Scripts\Duplicates\4.csv
```

appreciate any suggestions,

~TJ

Comment: I find it hard to believe that exporting to a file and importing back then filtering is faster that just doing everything in memory. But also, the `select-object Directory, Name` is mispositioned, it should be the last step before exporting.

Comment: I did the select early on because it was my hope that dropping some of the other properties early in the script would speed things up - I don't care about LastWriteTime for example. I put select-object near the end just now but don't notice any difference. The parent folder has about 10K child folders, it's specifically the group-object portion of the script that takes forever - I gave up after waiting 20 minutes, vs the 10 seconds group-object takes when I use CSV files.

Comment: Is this PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell Core 7+ ? Also, you should note, `.Directory` is not just a string, it's a `DirectoryInfo` object in itself which is massive if you try this with too many files (you are also missing `-File` in your `Get-ChildItem` call). Also your condition for determining if a file is a duplicate seems quite odd, how does grouping the objects by their parent folder help you determine that they're a duplicate or not?

Comment: The best way to determine if a file is a duplicate is to MD5sum them, or a bit more cumbersome but faster, to sequentially read the bytes and compare them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not [`Group-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) that is slow**, it's your grouping condition, you're asking it to group [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) objects by their [`.Directory` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directory?view=net-7.0#system-io-fileinfo-directory) which represents their parent folder [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0) instance. So, **you're asking the cmdlet to group objects by a very complex object as a grouping condition**, instead you could use the [`.DirectoryName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname?view=net-7.0#system-io-fileinfo-directoryname) as your grouping condition, which represents the parent directory's `FullName` property (a simple string) or you could use the [`.Directory.Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.name?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-name) which represents the parent's folder `Name` (also a simple string).

To summarize, the main reason why exporting to a CSV is faster in this case, is because when [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) receives your objects from pipeline, it calls the `ToString()` method on each object's property values, hence the `Directory` instance gets converted to its string representation (calling [`ToString()` to this instance ends up being the folder's `FullName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-tostring)).

As for your code, if you want to keep as efficient as possible without actually overcomplicating it:

```bash
Get-ChildItem M:\ -Recurse -File | & {
    process {
        if($_.Length -gt 500mb) { $_ }
    }
} | Group-Object DirectoryName | & {
    process {
        if($_.Count -gt 2) {
            foreach($object in $_.Group) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Directory = $_.Name # => This is the Parent Directory FullName
                    Name      = $object.Name
                }
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv M:\Misc\Scripts\Duplicates\4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to group them by the Parent `Name` instead of `FullName`, you could use:

```
Group-Object { $_.Directory.Name }
```